# Tablescraping from a website with ID using beautifulsoup

Tags: python, python-3.x, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, python-requests

Im having a problem with scraping the table of this website, I should be getting the heading but instead am getting

```
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'tbody'
```

Im a bit new to web-scraping so if you could help me out that would be great

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

URL = "https://www.collincad.org/propertysearch?situs_street=Willowgate&situs_street_suffix" \
      "=&isd%5B%5D=any&city%5B%5D=any&prop_type%5B%5D=R&prop_type%5B%5D=P&prop_type%5B%5D=MH&active%5B%5D=1&year=2021&sort=G&page_number=1"

s = requests.Session()

page = s.get(URL)
soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content, "lxml")

table = soup.find("table", id="propertysearchresults")
table_data = table.tbody.find_all("tr")

headings = []
for td in table_data[0].find_all("td"):
    headings.append(td.b.text.replace('\n', ' ').strip())

print(headings)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### What happens?

**Note:** *Always look at your soup first - therein lies the truth. The content can always be slightly to extremely different from the view in the dev tools.*

> ### Access Revoked
>
> Your IP address has been blocked.
>
> We
> detected irregular, bot-like usage of our Property Search originating
> from your IP address.  This block was instated to reduce stress on our
> webserver, to ensure that we're providing optimal site performance to
> the taxpayers of Collin County.
>
> *We have
> **not** blocked your ability to download [our
> data exports](http://collincad.org/downloads/viewcategory/42-appraisal-data-exports), which you can still use to acquire bulk property
> data.*

#### How to fix?

Add a `user-agent` to your requets so that it looks like your requesting with a "browser".

```
headers = {'user-agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/96.0.4664.110 Safari/537.36'}
page = s.get(URL,headers=headers)
```

Or as alternativ just download the results.

#### Example (scraping table)

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import pandas as pd

headers = {'user-agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/96.0.4664.110 Safari/537.36'}

URL = "https://www.collincad.org/propertysearch?situs_street=Willowgate&situs_street_suffix" \
      "=&isd%5B%5D=any&city%5B%5D=any&prop_type%5B%5D=R&prop_type%5B%5D=P&prop_type%5B%5D=MH&active%5B%5D=1&year=2021&sort=G&page_number=1"

s = requests.Session()

page = s.get(URL,headers=headers)
soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content, "lxml")

data = []
for row in soup.select('#propertysearchresults tr'):
    data.append([c.get_text(' ',strip=True) for c in row.select('td')])

pd.DataFrame(data[1:], columns=data[0])
```

#### Output

|  | Property ID ↓ Geographic ID ↓ | Owner Name | Property Address | Legal Description | 2021 Market Value |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2709013 R-10644-00H-0010-1 | PARTHASARATHY SURESH & ANITHA HARIKRISHNAN | 12209 Willowgate Dr Frisco, TX\xa0 75035 | Ridgeview At Panther Creek Phase 2, Blk H, Lot 1 | $513,019 |
| 2 | 2709018 R-10644-00H-0020-1 | JOSHI PRASHANT & SHWETA PANT | 12235 Willowgate Dr Frisco, TX\xa0 75035 | Ridgeview At Panther Creek Phase 2, Blk H, Lot 2 | $546,254 |
| 3 | 2709019 R-10644-00H-0030-1 | THALLAPUREDDY RAVENDRA & UMA MAHESWARI VEMULA | 12261 Willowgate Dr Frisco, TX\xa0 75035 | Ridgeview At Panther Creek Phase 2, Blk H, Lot 3 | $550,768 |
| 4 | 2709020 R-10644-00H-0040-1 | KULKARNI BHEEMSEN T & GOURI R | 12287 Willowgate Dr Frisco, TX\xa0 75035 | Ridgeview At Panther Creek Phase 2, Blk H, Lot 4 | $509,593 |
| 5 | 2709021 R-10644-00H-0050-1 | BALAM GANESH & SHANTHIREKHA LOKULA | 12313 Willowgate Dr Frisco, TX\xa0 75035 | Ridgeview At Panther Creek Phase 2, Blk H, Lot 5 | $553,949 |

...

Comment: Thank you so much! This fixed my issue.

Answer (score 2):

If you look at `page.content`, you will see that "Your IP address has been blocked".
[image]

You should add some headers to your request because the website is blocking your request. In your specific case, it will be enough to add a `User-Agent`:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

headers = {
    'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_11_5) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/50.0.2661.102 Safari/537.36'
}

URL = "https://www.collincad.org/propertysearch?situs_street=Willowgate&situs_street_suffix" \
      "=&isd%5B%5D=any&city%5B%5D=any&prop_type%5B%5D=R&prop_type%5B%5D=P&prop_type%5B%5D=MH&active%5B%5D=1&year=2021&sort=G&page_number=1"

s = requests.Session()

page = s.get(URL, headers=headers)
soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content, "lxml")

table = soup.find("table", id="propertysearchresults")
table_data = table.tbody.find_all("tr")

headings = []
for td in table_data[0].find_all("td"):
    headings.append(td.b.text.replace('\n', ' ').strip())

print(headings)
```

If you add headers, you will still have error, but in the row:

```
headings.append(td.b.text.replace('\n', ' ').strip())
```

You should change it to

```
headings.append(td.text.replace('\n', ' ').strip())
```

because `td` doesn't always have `b`.

Comment: Thank you! I just noticed that after the code was only working on another device

Answer (score 2):

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

URL = "https://www.collincad.org/propertysearch?situs_street=Willowgate&situs_street_suffix" \
      "=&isd%5B%5D=any&city%5B%5D=any&prop_type%5B%5D=R&prop_type%5B%5D=P&prop_type%5B%5D=MH&active%5B%5D=1&year=2021&sort=G&page_number=1"

s = requests.Session()
headers={"User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/96.0.4664.110 Safari/537.36"}
page = s.get(URL,headers=headers)
soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content, "lxml")
```

Finding Table Data:

```
column_data=soup.find("table").find_all("tr")[0]
column=[i.get_text() for i in column_data.find_all("td") if i.get_text()!=""]

row=soup.find("table").find_all("tr")[1:]
main_lst=[]
for row_details in row:
    lst=[]
    for i in row_details.find_all("td")[1:]:
        if i.get_text()!="":
            lst.append(i.get_text())
    main_lst.append(lst)
```

Converting to  `pandas` DataFrame:

```
import pandas as pd
df=pd.DataFrame(main_lst,columns=column)
```

Output:

```
Property ID↓ Geographic ID ↓    Owner Name  Property Address    Legal Description   2021 Market Value
0   2709013R-10644-00H-0010-1   PARTHASARATHY SURESH & ANITHA HARIKRISHNAN  12209 Willowgate DrFrisco, TX  75035    Ridgeview At Panther Creek Phase 2, Blk H, Lot 1    $513,019
.....
```